# Finding a Fourier series with $f(x)$ equal to something, what does this mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

So I've been asked to find the fourier series of $\frac{x}{\pi}$ between $[-\pi,\pi]$, which is fine, I can do this however, the question also says that "$f(x) = f(x + 2\pi)$" how does this change what I need to do?

I know the process of finding the fourier series/coefficients, I'm just not sure how the $f(x)=\dots$ part affects my answer/working out.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It refers to a periodic function, so basically if $x \notin [-\pi, \pi)$, then keep adding or subtracting $2\pi$ until you get to something which is in $[-\pi, \pi)$.

Comment: So, does it affect the method I would use to find the fourier series normally? Are there any steps I need to add or change?

Comment: Well that likely depends on what method you use to find the Fourier transform

Comment: @Maximus No, I think all you need to do is to show $f(x) = f(x + 2\pi)$ after finding the Fourier series using the usual method.